# How can I turn off data when my phone's screen is off and only let data come back on once per hour or so to sync apps?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life, mobile-data, data-connection

I have been using an app called Doze which turns off data when my phone's screen is off. I'd like to find a way that would turn off data when the screen is off but would turn on data once per hour or so, sync all apps to get new messages, updates, etc, and then turn data back off. Is this possible or do I need to write my own app?

I found having the mobile data off more than doubles battery life.

Comment: Device is not rooted. I forget which doze app now. I just upgraded to 6.0 and the battery life is a lot better. I'll look up macrodroid.

Comment: If you need help with Macrodroid, ping after detailing what you have tried by editing the question. BTW [Force Doze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze) is good (available for root and non root ). I use it with Macrodroid for a different scenario

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) introduced new OS features called [Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) to improve battery life. Doze defers data usage to short windows while the Android device is stationary. App Standby reduces the resource usage of applications that you don't use.

Personally, I found the battery life improvement from Doze to be tremendous. I often take my phone out of my pocket when I am not using it to keep it stationary to take advantage of the doze battery savings.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in the Play Store called [Juice Defender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender) which will do EXACTLY what you are looking for, although the time span for turning mobile data on and off is 15 (?) minutes and cannot be changed in the free version, you may have to upgrade to to Plus or Ultimate to get the exact time intervals you are looking for. It works well, at least the last time I used it which was probably the JellyBean era.